# vue18n with dynamic message key into the template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm using vue18n in my vue3 application.
For a specific component I would like to provide my template with the translation key dynamically.
So, I would like to use something like this:

```
<i18n-t keypath={{messageKey}} tag="p" id="myId>
...
</i18n-t>
```

So, instead of specifying a fixed string as a keypath, I would like to provide the message key dynamically.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to bind it, like `:keypath="messageKey"`